# How to write a wrapper http for web socket in java

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-websocket, java-websocket

I have a java websocket ws://localhost:8025/websockets/game
How do I write a wrapper http for it. So that I can use InputStream to connect to the http link: http://localhost:8025/websockets/game

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly what you want and why you wanna do this, but in this [repo](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket) the guy wrote his java websocket client and server using using purely javaSE, you can find something that fits your need. Since you want to use the InputStream to connect you will need do the client side upgrade verification by hand, I guess is better using plain Sockets, IMO has no sense using purely http single requests to connect to a ws, you will every time stucked in the upgrade request part, since plain http connections are on single reqest-response flow, may I'm wrong btw.